# TweenJS rotation smoothing bug

Tags: javascript, createjs, tweenjs

I found bug when using TweenJS today, problem when animating my tick-based response from socket.io server.
I get position and rotation every 1/10 second (10 ticks per second) and I smoothing this movement by TweenJS `.to()` function.

Position working like a charm, but rotation is buggy when I am switching around 0/360 degrees.

Server send for example `rotation: 350°` and in next tick server send `rotation: 10°`, but I dont want animate whole 340°, just 20°.
So I want animate from/to BUT by shortest way.
Plugin not working how supposted.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/bateriecz/wmj52eqd

EDIT: I found, that TweenJS is set to go shortest way as default, but not working for me

Comment: So I maked RotationPlugin works, but it not work 100% perfect. Its getting stucked on 0 degrees even when I am changing angle. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a rotation plugin already provided in TweenJS: https://github.com/CreateJS/TweenJS/tree/master/src/tweenjs/plugins

From the docs:

> After installation, by default all rotation tweens will rotate in the
>   shortest direction. For example, if you tween from `rotation=15` to
>   `rotation=330`, it will rotate counter-clockwise 45 degrees. You can
>   modify this behaviour by specifying a `rotationDir` tween value. A
>   value of `-1` will force CCW rotation, `1` will force CW, and `0` will
>   disable the plugin effects for that portion of the tween.

Note that you need the latest TweenJS (1.0.0), as it was heavily refactored since the last version (0.6.2). In the earlier version, there was a "SmartRotationPlugin", which worked the same way.

Comment: I read the docs twice thanks. Version 1.0.0 not include rotation plugin. you must download him and include after tweenjs. But plugin not working. It rotates one-time and lock on 0°. When I try rotating in next tick, rotation is still locked on 0°

Comment: Interesting. I can check it out.

Comment: Can you provide an example of this issue (ex. codepen or jsfiddle). A quick test of RotationPlugin is working for me.

`createjs.Tween.get(arrow, {loop: -1}).to({rotation: 350}, 1000)
   .to({rotation: 10}, 1000).to({rotation: 180}, 1000).to({rotation: 350}, 1000).to({rotation: 10}, 1000).to({rotation: 350}, 1000)`

Comment: That looks like a bug in the plugin. I'll try to dig into this in the next couple days.

Comment: @gskinner Did you found anything?